# Separator with Jenkins parameters with declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins

I have 50 parameters in my declarative jenkins pipeline, and it would be great to be able to make groups with separator.

I saw this plugin: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameter+Separator+Plugin

but it only does it with GUI, and I need to declare it in code, is it possible ?
EDIT: Here is the code:
I have only put 8 fields to be shorter, but 8 or 50, it should be the same

```
#!/bin/groovy

pipeline {
    agent { label 'ansible24' }

    parameters {
        // init script params
        string(name: 'NAME', defaultValue: 'Nightly Valid', description: '')
        string(name: 'CODE', defaultValue: 'NIGHTLY', description: '')
        string(name: 'VERSION', defaultValue: '1.0.0', description: ' ')
        string(name: 'URL', defaultValue: "https://my.gitlab.net/config-daily.git", description: '')
        // What I need is programmatically add a separator like:
        // addSeparator()
        string(name: 'ADMIN_MAIL', defaultValue: 'mail@as.com', description: '')
        string(name: 'PUBLIC_DOMAIN', defaultValue: 'domain.com', description: '')
        string(name: 'PROVIDER', defaultValue: 'rhone', description: ' Define target virtualization provider. values : rhone, no-infra (read carefully use case)')
        choice(name: 'BASTION_STATE', choices: "present\nabsent", description: "Bastion state ")
    }

    stages {
        stage("Run Init script") {
            steps {
                script {
                    def filename = "${WORKSPACE}/${params.CODE}/configuration.yml"
                    def yaml = readYaml file: filename

                    // General data
                    yaml.global.name = "${params.NAME}".toString()
                    yaml.global.code = "${params.CODE}".toString()
                    yaml.global.admin_mail = "${params.ADMIN_MAIL}".toString()
                    yaml.global.public_domain = "${params.PUBLIC_DOMAIN}".toString()
                    yaml.global.provider = "${params.PROVIDER}".toString()
                    yaml.global.bastion.state = "${params.BASTION_STATE}"
                    sh "rm $filename"

                    writeYaml file: filename, data: yaml
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would give a try with a direct manipulation of a parameter array in Groovy.

Some examples:

```
http://grails.asia/groovy-array-manipulation-examples
```

With pipeline you're using a groovy anyway.

Comment: I don't find a way to do it. I can't even dump list of params. I would need a more explicit answer, sorry :( is it posible ?

Comment: Re-edit your question and write some example of your 50 params and how your should use them. So it be more clear to me how to help.

Comment: updated. I added 8 fields, I will get the values and update a yaml file. But as I have a lot of field, I would like to be able to separate sections from code